# Sign of function containing the cdf and pdf of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I need to proove that

$\Big( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2} \Big)N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})\Big( 2N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2-3N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})+1\Big)+n(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})\Big(2N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2-3N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})+1\Big) \geq 0$
for all $x \in R$. Where $N()$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable and $n()$ the pdf of a standard normal variable.

I tried to do the proof by parts, by looking at the sign of pieces of the equation. For example I know that $\Big(2N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2-3N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})+1\Big)\leq 0$ and $\Big(2N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2-2N(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})+1\Big)\geq 0$ but I do not know how to continue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not check the details yet, but usually when you need to study the sign of something, you should try to factorize it and then study the sign of the factors. $\displaystyle \left[\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma^2} \Phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right) + \phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right)\right]\left[2\Phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right) - 1\right]\left[\Phi\left(\frac {x - \mu} {\sigma}\right) -
 1\right]$

Answer (score 0):

First, make your life easier by simplifying the notation.  If you let $z=(x-\mu)/\sigma,$ $\phi=n((x-\mu)/\sigma),$ and $\Phi=N((x-\mu)/\sigma)$, your desired inequality turns into $$(z \Phi +\phi) (2\Phi-1)(\Phi-1) \ge0.$$  We know $0<\Phi<1$, so $\Phi-1<0$ so you want $$ (z\Phi+\phi)(2\Phi-1)\le 0.$$  If $z>0$ you know $2\Phi-1>0$ so in this case you want $$z\Phi+\phi\le0.$$  But in this case, each of $z,$ $\phi,$ and $\Phi$ is positive, so this cannot happen.

If $z<0$, note that $\Phi-1<0$ so now you want $$ z\Phi+\phi\ge0.$$  This is equivalent to wanting, for $w>0$, $$-w(1-\Phi(w))+\phi(w)\ge0,$$ which is to say, $$(1-\Phi(w))\le w\phi(w).$$
This last is true (see section 26.2 of Abramowitz and Stegun, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, say).

So your wish comes true for $x<\mu$ and fails for $x>\mu$.